# Concurrent Transaction in Reliable Dictionary with locks

Tags: .net, azure-service-fabric

I am creating a Bidding Service using ReliableCollection.  I am still confused on the locking aspect of ReliableDictionary. Let's say TX1 is bidding for $20 and TX2 bidding on the same $20, I have a logic which check bid collection and fails it for any transaction which reaches last. Written the below code, Is it the right way of doing it or it can be improved to avoid dead locks?

```
using (var tx = this.AuctionStateManager.CreateTransaction())
        {
            //added an update lock for getting value
           var  bidOldState = await itemBidStore.TryGetValueAsync(tx,ItemId, LockMode.Update);

            if (bidOldState.HasValue)
            {
                //checking if its a valid bid or not. If No then abort the transaction
                var bidComputedRequest = BidCompute.ProcessBidState(bidOldState, bidNewRequest);

                //if it's a valid bid then add to dictionary
                await itemBidStore.AddOrUpdateAsync(tx: tx,
                                                   key: ItemId,
                                                   addValue: bidComputedRequest,
                                                   updateValueFactory: (key, value) => bidComputedRequest,
                                                   timeout: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Constants.BidStoreAsyncTimeout),
                                                   cancellationToken: cancelRequest);

            }



            await tx.CommitAsync();
        }
```

Comment: If you want the second transaction to fail, don't use addorupdate. Instead use TryAdd and check the result.

Comment: my key is itemId so I have to update as well in case of new Bid for that item.